# Graphing data live from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, tkinter

I'm trying to graph data live (or look dynamic) using animate from a CSV file that I write to from receiving data over TCP from an instrument.

Here is my code:

```
def animate(i):
  xs = []
  ys = []
  with open('C:/Users/aeros/Desktop/flashDump.csv') as graph_data:
    for line in graph_data:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        if len(line) > 1:
            line.split(" ")
            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
ax1.clear()
ax1.plot(xs, ys)
```

And then I call this in my GUI tkinter mainloop

```
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1000)
    plt.show()
```

Here is what my CSV file usually looks like when I write data to it.

[image]

So obviously the file isn't parsed right because it's not in the first column and there's a space between the data, and when using animate I get the error of x, y too many values to unpack.

Appreciate any help in parsing the file correctly and plotting the data in real-time.

Comment: Hint:Consider empty columns as empty strings. You potentially have 4 fields in data which you want to fit in x and y

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, but I'm not sure how to skip over those columns or label them as empty so I can correctly have the x & y cols as the data.

Comment: `line.split(" ")` What do you think this is doing? `split` will return a list. fetch your data based on the index. That would be the easiest way to deal with this.

Comment: Ahh I see, so I would want index of cols 1 & 3? How would I assign x & y to those cols and then iterate down for each pair of values?

Comment: conider you have a list `my_list` then `x,y =mylist[1],mylist[3]`

Comment: Sorry for lack of understanding, but I'm still confused on how to apply that when reading the file in iteration

Comment: Jon can you tell me what this line is for `if not line.strip():
            continue`? I am not convinced you need it at all.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. It is not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue lies here:

```
if len(line) > 1:
    line.split(" ")
    x, y = line.split(',') # specifically this line.
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)
```

The `x, y = split(',')` could work if you were working with only one comma per line because you would create a 2 index list and each would assign to x and y but anything bigger would not work here.

Update:

Here is a better option to work with the format of your CSV.

First we need to `rstrip()` the line. What this will do is remove the `\n` from the line. This will help later.

Next we need to do `split(",")` to create our list. This list will have 3 index points. The first value from column B the empty string from column C and the 2nd value form column D. Then you can assign the index to each of your other list.

```
def animate():
    xs = []
    ys = []
    with open('flashDump.csv') as graph_data:
        for line in graph_data:
            rstriped = line.rstrip()
            if len(rstriped) > 1:
                line_list = rstriped.split(",")
                xs.append(line_list[0])
                ys.append(line_list[2])
                print(xs, ys)

animate()
```

Comment: He is trying to read from csv so I presume there would be `','` as well on which one might need to do a split on. Or you can read the file from csv.reader

Comment: @mad_ Ah yes you are right. I missunderstood that he loaded the CSV into a data type or string prior to the if statement. I will rework my answer.

Comment: Okay I see going off of your example and mad's. I seem to be in the correct areas reading the data but now I get this error : ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 6760.8,, Any reason there would be two commas after the value?

Comment: You should strip the commas out. The commas are left over from the `split()` method.

Comment: Ah got it! Now just a quick side question, these values are actually separate y vals for two different readings, would it be possible to append a X axis for time (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...)

Comment: @JonMontgomery Not sure I understand what you mean by append a X axis. Could you elaborate a little. I am sure what you want to do will probably be a simple loop.

Comment: Just a X axis of time for each value pair. So the current values are separate readings that should be on the Y axis vs time.

Comment: @JonMontgomery That should probably be in a new question. It would be easier to articulate an answer that way. I have also updated my answer with a cleaner for loop for getting your xs and ys values.